# NativeScript build failed after adding Telerik UI plugin with error GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: telerik, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

After adding recent Telerik UI plugin in my NativeScript app my BUILD is getting fail with the error "**GC overhead limit exceeded**". Even if PLATFORM 'REMOVE/ADD' commands are not working as long as I've not removed the Telerik UI plugin.

I want Telerik UI plugin for sideDrawer component in my app.

**Screenshot of build fail**

[image]

**Screenshot for tns environment**

[image]

**Code for package.json file**

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.bhramaan",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "2.1.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "0.1.1",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^3.0.1",
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^1.2.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.9.0",
    "babel-types": "6.9.0",
    "babylon": "6.8.0",
    "filewalker": "0.1.2",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }
}
```

Any guess, what's might've gone wrong ?

**------------------ISSUE FIXED-----------------------------**

After a lot of searching & breaking my head finally, manage to build my app successfully. Needed to add following piece of code in my `app.gradle`

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

So. now it's like

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    generatedDensities = []
    applicationId "org.nativescript.bhramaan"
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that the latest versions of nativescript-angular (0.2.0) and nativescript-telerik-ui (1.2.0) were implemented with the latest angular 2 RC3 version. As I see from the package.json you are using the RC1 which has been changed by the angular team a lot in the RC3 version. It is recommended to update to it as soon as possible.

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov Hey, how to update all angular dependencies? Can't able to get the right NPM commands.

Comment: You should be able to do 'npm install @angular/core' for the core modules etc. or 'tns plugin add @angular/core' both of those should get the latest version of angular/core. You should be able to do the same for any other of the angular modules that are required.

A simpler way would be to change your package.json to point to the RC3 version, for example you can see the package.json of the nativescript-ui-samples-angular repo: https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/release/sdkAngular/package.json